# Given a range of dates, how to capture rows that has at least one of those dates in another range of dates?

Tags: mysql

Here's my problem:

I have a table of events, with two dates, a starting one and a finishing one for each.

I want to be able to filter all the events which any of it's days fall into the upper and lower filter. Example:

```
Event 1
start: 2019-1-1
end: 2019-1-5
```

Using

```
WHERE (start BETWEEN "'.$filterstart.'" AND "'.$filterend.' 23:59:59")
 OR (end BETWEEN "'.$filterstart.'" AND "'.$filterend.' 23:59:59")
```

this will catch almost all events required, except for this filter:

```
filterstart: 2019-1-3
filterend: 2019-1-3
```

Since the filter starts and finishes between the start and end date. How can I also catch those?

Comment: you're open to SQL injection ^^ should resolve immediately

Comment: `WHERE DATE(start) BETWEEN '{$filterstart}' AND '{$filterstart}'
OR DATE(end) BETWEEN '{$filterstart}' AND '{$filterstart}'`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230676/352329 @AlbertoMoro

Comment: @treyBake the fields are sanitized before concatenating. Goo luck injecting anything after a date parser.

Comment: @monxas I used to think that too.. but then I learned a bit more about SQL injection - it's still unsafe ..

Comment: @AlbertoMoro that doesn't answer my question

Comment: @treyBake this is an small update to a big old project in which mysql injection is sorted using mysqli.real-escape-string and other data validation. We just cannot migrate the whole project to other solution and this one works.